# How to Create a Repeatable Meta Box

Tags: javascript, metabox

I would like to know how to create repeatable meta-boxes like in this video:  http://www.screenr.com/a17s [starts at around 40 seconds].  I saw an answer on how one creates a repeatable section within a meta-box, but I want to know how to repeat the entire box (as seen in the video).

Comment: What you showed is not a repeatable metabox, but a custom box that uses the default admin UI styling on a custom settings page.

Answer (score 2):

[WP Alchemy](http://farinspace.com/wpalchemy-metabox/) and [Advanced custom fields](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) both support this feature already.